# grunt-contrib-uglify and ecmascript 6

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

Does anyone know when will uglify be able to support Ecmascript6? I've tried using it with a simple JS 6 file and it will throw an error whenever it finds JS code (ex.: let).

thanks.

Luis